# Validation error object in React from Laravel passport API

Tags: reactjs, object, laravel-passport

How may I access the email value from within the following object in a ReactJs application?

```
{"message":{"email":["The email field is required."]}}
```

It is a validation error that has been returned and I want to display the message under the email input field.

This piece of code worked for me in vanilla js but it fails in ReactJs

```
const errors = {"message":{"firstname":["The firstname field is required."],"lastname":["The lastname field is required."],"email":["The email field is required."],"password":["The password field is required."]}}

const data = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(errors);

// console.log("this...",data.message.value);

const descriptor1 = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(data.message.value, "firstname");
const descriptor2 = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(data.message.value, "lastname");
const descriptor3 = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(data.message.value, "email");
const descriptor4 = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(data.message.value, "password");

console.log(descriptor1.value[0]);
console.log(descriptor2.value[0]);
console.log(descriptor3.value[0]);
console.log(descriptor4.value[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Buggy**

```
.catch(err => {
        setErrors(err.response.request.response);           
        setLoading(false);
      });
```

**Correct:**

```
.catch(err => {
         setErrors(err.response.data.errors);
        setLoading(false);
      });
```